# gsutil to copy anonymously from s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

Goal is for gsutil to copy anonymously from s3:// to gs://.

Boto supports s3 anonymous connections, but I'm not sure how to get gsutil to use the anonymous connection method.

I've added this to `~/.boto` with no luck. It still expects to have `[Credentials]` defined for AWS:

```
[s3]
anon = True
```

Any experience/advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gsutil bug - anonymous auth is only used if no credentials (for gs or s3) are available.

If you are reading anonymously from s3:// and writing anonymously (to a publicly-writable bucket) in gs://, you can simply run with no ~/.boto file and it will work.

If you need to combine anonymous and credentialed requests, for example reading anonymously to s3 while writing to a non-public GCS bucket, you'll need to wait for a fix to [this Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/298).

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you're looking to copy a lot of data from S3 to GS you may want to try the [GCS Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/getting-started) (although I don't think it supports anonymous S3 access). This will allow you to copy without sending the bits via your machine.